# Reverse part of a linked list

Tags: algorithm, c, linked-list, interview-questions

I'm  learning data structures. I'm working on linked lists at the moment, and I'd like to have a strong grasp on them. Below is the last problem I solved. I'd like to know what you think of the solution and what can be done better.

The problem consists of reversing a linked list from position `m` to position `n`.
`1 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ length of list`. If we have a list `1->2->3->4->5->NULL, m = 2 and n = 4`, the function should return `1->4->3->2->5->NULL`.

```
   /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
struct ListNode* reverseBetween(struct ListNode* head, int m, int n) {
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL || m - n == 0)
    {
        return head;
    }
    struct ListNode* prev = NULL, *cur = head;
    struct ListNode* before_m_node, *m_node, *after_n_node;
    int count = 0;

    // find m node, after loop cur points to m node, prev gets node befor or  NULL if there is none
    while (count != m)
    {
        ++count;
        if (count == m)
        {
            break;
        }
        prev = cur, cur = cur->next;
    }
    m_node = cur;
    before_m_node = prev;
    prev = cur, cur = cur->next;

    // now we look for n node, cur is currently pointing to node after m, prev points to node before
    // we will reverse links as we go and after loop cur will point to n node
    while (count != n)
    {
        ++count;
        if (count == n)
        {
            break;
        }
        struct ListNode* temp = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev = cur, cur = temp;
    }

    after_n_node = cur->next;

    // if first node is not head of the list
    if (before_m_node != NULL)
    {
        cur->next = prev;
        m_node->next = after_n_node;
        before_m_node->next = cur;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        cur->next = prev;
        m_node->next = after_n_node;
        return cur;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/reversing-a-linked-list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Redundancy in while loops

Your while loop has a condition that never gets used because there is an if statement inside the loop that actually ends the loop.  For example:

> ```
> while (count != m)
> {
>     ++count;
>     if (count == m)
>     {
>         break;
>     }
>     prev = cur, cur = cur->next;
> }
> ```

You could simplify this by merging the increment into the loop condition.  Also, I don't using the comma operator to put two statements on one line.  So I would write your loop like this:

```
while (++count < m)
{
    prev = cur;
    cur  = cur->next;
}
```

And your other loop would look like this:

```
while (++count < n)
{
    struct ListNode* temp = cur->next;
    cur->next = prev;
    prev      = cur;
    cur       = temp;
}
```

## Use typedef

I suggest using a typedef so you don't have to use `struct` so much.  For example:

```
typedef struct ListNode {
     int val;
     struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;
```

And then use just `ListNode` instead of `struct ListNode` everywhere.

Comment: The new version of the loop does not behave as the old one in the case  where the initial value of `count` is the same as the value of `m`, i.e. if the value of `m` is `0`. I know the question assumes `m` to be greater than `0`, but...

Comment: @ErwanLegrand I changed the conditions to make the loops equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @JS1's comments. I'd add a few others.

- You could consider replacing your `while` loops with function calls. This could increase readability somewhat and eliminate the need for commenting at all, if you have nice function names. This would make your code more compact, though arguably slow it down since now you've got a function call. However, there are [some C compile options that would support inline-ing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151168/does-ansi-c-not-know-the-inline-keyword).
- The more succinct a comment is, the more likely it is to be read. Even if you don't make new functions, I'd recommend shortening your comments. For example, I'd probably shorten:

  `// now we look for n node, cur is currently pointing to node after m, prev points to node before
  // we will reverse links as we go and after loop cur will point to n node`

to:

```
    // count to the nth code
    // reverse links during traversal
```

- Some of your naming could be more descriptive. For example, you could rename `count` to `position_indicator` since you are really tracking position rather than a count.
- Reduce repetitive code. In particular, you could move these two statements out of the `if...else` branch at the end of your function since you write the identical statement in each branch right now:

  `cur->next = prev;
  m_node->next = after_n_node;`

Answer (score 0):

How about some defensive programming ?

- Check that `m` is `1` or greater
- Check that `n` greater or equal to`m`
- Check that pointers are not `NULL` in the loops (i.e. that you
  have not reached the end of the list sooner than expected)

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer would lead to a segmentation fault, that is a crash.

Regarding the loops, the idiomatic C way of looping while incrementing an integer is to use `for` rather than `while`:

```
for (count = 1; count < m; count++) {
    if (!cur) {
        // Error handling here
        break;
    }
    prev = cur;
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

And assuming C99 or later, you would define `count` within the loop:

```
for (int count = 1; count < m; count++) {
```